# Batch redirection to two locations

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been having some troubles redirecting a batch file to a log file as well as having it display in the command console.

Is this even possible with windows batch, or do I have to resort to a simple program which intercepts stdout and writes the stream to a file and to stdout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this (properly) with just the built-in tools, you probably need to use a [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) utility like the Win32 GNU ports ([this](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or [this](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)) or [mtee](http://www.commandline.co.uk/mtee/index.html)

**Edit:**
You can of course use the FOR batch command, but the output is not live, you have to wait for the command to finish:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
goto main

:TEE
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('%~2') DO (
    >>"%~1" echo.%%A
    echo.%%A
)
goto :EOF

:main
call :TEE "%temp%\log.txt" "ping -n 2 localhost"
```